# HTML & JS - How to modify CSS class atributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I have the following code and nothing happens:

HTML:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="log-oth.js"></script>
</head>

<body onResize="nav_fontsz()">
```

JS:

```
function nav_fontsz(){
    var nav = document.querySelectorAll('.nav');
    var navbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-button');

    for (i=0 ; i<navbtn.length ; i++){
        navbtn[i].style.fontSize = (nav[0].style.width / 3.5)+'px';}

    alert(nav[0].style.width);
}
```

plus, the alert box shows nothing, not even 0

Answer (score 0):

The function probably runs but there are errors in your code.

`navbtn` will be empty because this code runs before any DOM Nodes are rendered. This is why you see a lot of the `$(document).ready()` stuff, you need to wait till your DOM is rendered before you try to fetch the nodes.

Also, `nav` is undefined so the alert wont show either. I'm guessing you commented it out because `document.getElementsByClassName()` also gives you an empty NodeList.

If you want to make sure the resize handler runs, just put `alert("foo");` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

You have three different issues, the first of which is a simple typo:

1. The function does not run because you are missing parentheses when calling it in onresize.  Change it to this:

   ```
   <body onresize="nav_fontsz()">
   ```
2. You are selecting elements that do not exist at the time the script is loaded on the page.  You could fix that by moving the lines that set 'w' and 'navbtn' inside the nav_fontsz() function, which is called after the DOM loads, as seen in my sample code below.
3. You are using querySelectorAll but treating the results like a single object, when in actuality you are selecting 1 or more elements.  Treat 'navbtn' as a result set and iterate through the set, setting the font size on each element, as seen in my sample code below.

JavaScript (log-oth.js):

```
function nav_fontsz() {
    var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;
    var navbtn = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-button');

    alert('Running...');

    var w = window.innerWidth;

    if (w < 800) {
        for (i = 0; i < navbtn.length; i++) {
            alert(navbtn.length);
            navbtn[i].style.fontSize = (w / 3.5) + 'px';
        }
    }

    alert('Done!');
}
```

HTML:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="log-oth.js"></script>
</head>
<body onresize="nav_fontsz()">
    <ul>
        <li class="nav-button">Nav 1</li>
        <li class="nav-button">Nav 2</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/9kq1dv10/